# Why we need TFX if we have airflow for orchestration

Tags: airflow, tfx

I still don't get why we need TFX. TFX will convert your defined pipeline to Airflow DAG and run it on airflow, I could just write my pipelines in python and use Airflow's PythonOperator to build a pipeline directly right? why bother learning another wrapper on top of it?  What else TFX offers that cannot be done by just using airflow+TF+Spark/Beam

Answer (score 0):

> I could just write my pipelines in python and use Airflow's PythonOperator to build a pipeline directly right?

You can! Depending on how you define a ***pipeline*** of course.

Here is the definition of TFX, from it's [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide):

"*TFX is a Google-production-scale machine learning (ML) platform based on TensorFlow. It provides a configuration framework and shared libraries to integrate common components needed to define, launch, and monitor your machine learning system.*"

And to make a Production ML System

[image]

according to [engineers at Tensorflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drYM04t57tU).

So, if you can define a whole system where you are able cover all these steps in Airflow DAG's, sure you don't need TFX.

---

P.S. :

It comes down to the **problem** you are trying to solve. Here are some questions to think about.

- Do you have the data needed at hand, is it valuable?
- Do you need to adjust it before giving it to a model?
- Which model should you use?
- Are you going to re-train the model as you get new data? If so what is the period of this process should be?
- As you are doing inference - or serving your model - how are you going to use the predicted results?
- What is your threshold for evaluating the success of your service? What metrics should you use?

To learn more, you can check [here](https://www.krasamo.com/apache-airflow/).

Answer (score 0):

TFX is a Google-production-scale machine learning (ML) platform and provides a configuration framework and shared libraries to integrate common components needed to define, launch, and monitor your machine learning system. For more details, please refer to [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide).

Advantages of using TFX:

- Including Apache Airflow, TFX is designed to be portable to multiple
  environments and orchestration frameworks such as Apache Beam and
  Kubeflow Pipelines.
- TFX provides set of standard components and libraries and the base
  functionality for many of the standard components which helps
  implementing ML pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr Airflow is not an effective scheduler for Continuous Training Pipelines, TFX is using it as a fallback mechanism for engineers who do not need the full power of CTP.

TFX shines when it comes to CTP. `They need to have data-driven execution of their components, to`:

1. `operate asynchronously at different iteration intervals`
2. `reuse results from previous runs`

`CTP cannot be implemented effectively as the repeated execution of one-off pipelines at scheduled intervals`, aka task-based, such as Airflow.

`Developers who are used to seeing jobs execute in sequence, as they were defined in a directed acyclic graph (DAG), are not accustomed to runs being triggered by the presence of a specific configuration of artifacts, as represented by the pipeline state. As a solution, TFX introduces a framework that allows users to specify job dependency as they would in a taskbased orchestration system. This also allows users of the open source version of TFX to orchestrate their TFX pipelines with task-based orchestration systems like Apache Airflow.`

Reference for gray text: [Continuous Training for Production ML in the TensorFlow Extended (TFX) Platform](https://www.usenix.org/conference/opml19/presentation/baylor)

Comment: The CTP of TFX is not open sourced right?

Comment: CTP is achieved by the use of TFX components, which are released via the Apache license.

Comment: could you please post the link here? Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/master/LICENSE